# Intellij build fails while mvn build using command line passes

Tags: intellij-idea, build

Able to build the project using mvn command line. But intellij fails to build the project. I tried the following things:

1. `mvn clean idea:idea`
2. Reimported the libraries.
3. Rebuilt the project after clearing caches in intellij.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Reimporting the package from your `pom.xml` again.

Go to file->project from existing source-> select your pom.xml.

Above will recreate your project structure again.

[image]